# Materialize CSS & Angular 5 - Sticky Footer

Tags: css, angular, materialize

I am trying to get my footer to be stickied to the bottom when the page's content doesn't reach the end of the screen.

I am building an Angular 5 application.

I added the `<header>`, `<main>` and `<footer>` tags to my `app.component.html`.

I tried adding the required css from Materialize everywhere. In the global css file, the app.component css file, even in the Materialize css. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my `app.component.html`:

```
<header>
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</header>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</main>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The `app-footer` starts with this:

```
<footer class="page-footer blue darken-2">
```

I'd like to know where to put the css required for my footer to go to the bottom of the page.

Comment: can you share your css. I used the css from http://www.prashant-kumar.in/add-sticky-footer-materialize-design/ and was able fix the problem

Comment: I used the same CSS. That's the CSS that's mentioned on the Materialize footer page. I'm just not sure where to put it. Although i thought that when I put it in the global file it should've worked...

Answer (score 1):

A fast answer is to put the html that is inside your FooterComponent in the index.html.
Surround your  tag with the  tag, like this example:

```
<body>

  <main>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <!-- your footer html here -->
  </footer>

</body>
```

(remember to erase your html inside your FooterComponent)

Answer (score 0):

In your AppComponent.html:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<main>
    <div class="row">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</main>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

and change your style.css:

```
body > app-root { 
    display: flex; 
    min-height: 100vh; 
    flex-direction: column;
}
main { 
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### David Ortiz's answer worked for me!

***However***
It should be noted that the chunk:

```
body > app-root { 
    display: flex; 
    min-height: 100vh; 
    flex-direction: column;
}
main { 
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

had to be placed in the sitewide `styles.css` file for it to work.